# What is the correct way of reading single line of data by using Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm very new to Linq, I can find multi-line data reading examples everywhere (by using foreach()), but what is the correct way of reading a single line of data? Like a classic **Product Detail** page.

Below is what I tried:

```
var q = from c in db.Products
    where c.ProductId == ProductId
    select new { c.ProductName, c.ProductDescription, c.ProductPrice, c.ProductDate };

string strProductName = q.First().ProductName.ToString();
string strProductDescription = q.First().ProductDescription.ToString();
string strProductPrice = q.First().ProductPrice.ToString();
string strProductDate = q.First().ProductDate.ToString();
```

The code looks good to me, but when I see the actual SQL expressions generated by using SQL Profiler, it makes me scared! The program executed **four Sql expressions** and they are **exactly the same**!

Because I'm reading **four columns** from a single line. I think I must did something wrong, so I was wondering what is the right way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: One way to update your intuition might be this: Note that First() is a *method* rather than a *property* - this suggests it's going to *do something*. You only want to *do something* once, so only call First() once (and as noted below, consider FirstOrDefault()).

Comment: For me, what would make me scared instead is *not* being able to use LINQ in my projects. I can't live without it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the First() extension method would throw the `System.InvalidOperationException` when no element in a sequence satisfies a specified condition.

If you use the `FirstOrDefault()` extension method, you can test against the returned object to see if it's null or not.

**FirstOrDefault** returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements; in this case the default value of a Product should be null. Attempting to access the properties on this null object will throw `ArgumentNullException`

```
var q = (from c in db.Products
    where c.ProductId == ProductId
    select new { c.ProductName, c.ProductDescription, c.ProductPrice, c.ProductDate }).FirstOrDefault();

if (q != null)
{
    string strProductName = q.ProductName;
    string strProductDescription = q.ProductDescription;
    string strProductPrice = q.ProductPrice;
    string strProductDate = q.ProductDate;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't have to cast each Property `ToString()` if you're object model is setup correctly. ProductName, ProductDescription, etc.. should already be a string.

The reason you're getting 4 separate sql queries, is because each time you call `q.First().<PropertyHere>` linq is generating a new Query.

Answer (score 5):

```
var q = (from c in db.Products
         where c.ProductId == ProductId
         select new { c.ProductName, c.ProductDescription, c.ProductPrice, c.ProductDate }
        ).First ();

string strProductName = q.ProductName.ToString();
string strProductDescription = q.ProductDescription.ToString();
string strProductPrice = q.ProductPrice.ToString();
string strProductDate = q.ProductDate.ToString();
```